# Array Undefined offset Notice in if condition [php]

Tags: php

i know my first element in my array[zero index] is NULL and i want to check that in my {if} condition. but i have a notice here. what can i do to resolve the notice?
my simple code:

```
$arr = [];
$arr[1] = '1';
if($arr[0] === NULL)
    echo 'if';
else
    echo 'else';
```

Comment: you first sentense _"my first element in my array[zero index] is NULL"_ is not 100% correct: It's not defined, which is something different to being NULL!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is check if the variable relative to that index of the array has been initialized/set. For example:

```
$arr = [];
$arr[1] = '1';
if(!isset($arr[0]))
    echo 'if';
else
    echo 'else';
```

Comment: Careful with `isset()`, because it will return `false` if `$arr[0]` is set to a falsey value (like `null`). It would probably be better to use `array_key_exists()`.